# Binding nggrid with . in json object

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am having an issue while I am trying to bind ng-grid to json array returned from server that contains . in the column names. To demonstrate the problem, I have created a plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eXuPy4dNHyJqeZ5bV2lB?p=preview

If you notice in the plunker, if I use xyz.name, I cannot bind the data to ng-grid. However, if I replace it with xyz_name, it works perfectly fine. I understand that ng-grid uses . notation to go to next level of json array to get the fields. I am hoping to get a workaround that will work with the data I have.

Any suggestions/work arounds for achieving this ?

thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The solution is to define a cellTemplate for this column using row.entity[col.field] instead of default row.getProperty(col.field) method.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
    "xyz.name": "Moroni",
    age: 50
  }, {
    "xyz.name": "Enos",
    age: 34
  }];



  var colDefs = [{
      field: 'xyz.name',
      cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div>'
    }, {
      field: 'age'
    }

  ];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: colDefs
  };
});
```

- The [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xeLCGuSjrbGyiPgw7q75?p=preview) is working perfectly now.
  http://plnkr.co/edit/xeLCGuSjrbGyiPgw7q75?p=preview

#### so, what's wrong with default cellTemplate?

the default cellTemplate used in ng-grid is like this:

`<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span></div>`

it uses `row.getProperty()` method which eventually calls angular [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service. it will evaluate the argument which treats the `.` as child operator.

so in this case 'xyz.name' actually maps to json data structure like this:

`xyz:{name: "moroni"}`

`row.entity[col.field]` just maps the data like a hashmap, so it will serve the purpose here.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. This solved the issue described in the plunker. Hopefully, I can solve it on my code which uses dynamic binding with dynamic colDefs and JSON Data. Will keep you posted.